# getting values from a table where value is not null

Tags: linq, entity-framework

When doing an EF query in the code behind using LINQ, how does one go about retrieving only those items in a nullable column that actually have data?

for example;

```
Dim unit = (From d in ctx.Inventories
           Where d.ProductId Is Not Null
           Select d).ToList()
```

Where obviously that query doesnt work, how does one go about this?

Comment: You have valid inventory data that doesn't have a ProductId?

Comment: the inventory table is composed of components and products, each is nullable, and yes i probably should have two tables but its only 11 items in total. Is this doable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `ProductId` is likely a nullable type, you should be able to do:

```
Dim unit = (From d in ctx.Inventories
       Where d.ProductId.HasValue
       Select d).ToList()
```